# Restore GPG Cache Passphrase

Tags: debian, password, gpg, cache

Moving all my stuff to another computer realized i forgot the passphrase for one of my GPG keys as I don't use it much because it is cached. Are the cached passphrases stored here: `/usr/local/var/cache/gnupg` ?

Maybe I can copy that folder to the new computer and cached passwords will transfer the same?

Both running Debian 8.

Answer (score 1):

GPG passphrases aren't cached anywhere on disk. If they were, that would be a huge security hole. They can be temporarily stored **in memory** to avoid the hassle of typing it, if you set the relevant option.

If you have lost the passphrase of your private key, your key is unusable as there's no way to recover a passphrase.